# Phonegap 2.0.0 keyup event

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, jquery-events

I have the following divs:

```
<div id="header">
  <input type="text" id="input_navbar"/>
</div>

<div id="core">
  Listing
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

Then I have the code:

```
$('#input_navbar').on('keyup',function(e){
  $("#status").html($('#input_navbar').val());
});
```

The keyup event never fires up. If I replace it with keypress or change it works fine. Is there something specific that has to be kept in mind when it comes to keyup event?

Comment: i am having the same problem! Have you found any solution for that? I am pretty pissed... the eclipse-console logs every down and up event but i cant get them! If you have anything i would be very happy ;) -inflight validations sucks this way^^

Comment: It's a bug apparently. I have logged it but I haven't got any return yet... I am not sure a 100% that it's bug I have read the latter on a google group discussion. I'll post whenever I get news on that ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in PhoneGap 2.1.0.  It's not available yet, I had to build it myself.

Comment: spotted on. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 0):

Just tested the following code for keyup event with the below environment and it works:

Phonegap: 2.0.0

```
<script type="text/javascript>
function test()
{
 alert('Keyup event working');
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
Keyup test<input type="text" onkeyup="javascript:test();" id="test">
```

[Keyup](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeyup.asp) event is fired when a key is released and [keypress](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp) is released when a key is pressed. 
Maybe you should consider using the right event?